# My scanner class is not being detected

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Here is my code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;          // Access System.out
public class NumericInput
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // Declarations
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
     System.out.println("Please enter two decimal values:");
        double num1;
        double num2;
        num1 = scan.nextDouble();
        num2 = scan.nextDouble();
        double num3;
        num3 = num1 - num2;
        num3 = (int)num3;
        num3 = (double)num3;

        System.out.println("The difference is: " + num3);
  }

}
```

I'm doing work for my AP class and neither me nor my dad can find out whats wrong and Google didn't help very much so if anybody can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You named your scanner `input` instead of `scan` or vice versa. You probably named it `input` and then copied the `scan.nextDouble();` line from a website without realizing the `scan` needs to be your `Scanner` variable: `input`.

Comment: very seem like a homework.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared a `Scanner` as input, but seem to be trying to use `scan` instead;

```
num1 = scan.nextDouble();
num2 = scan.nextDouble();
```

Should be

```
num1 = input.nextDouble();
num2 = input.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `input.nextDouble()` instead of `scan.nextDouble()`. Also, you might want to do `hasNextdouble()` check.